# change structure of json in python

Tags: python, json

I have hundreds of **json** files, having structure like this:

```
    [
        {
            "INVOICE": {
                "label": {
                    "box": {
                        "left": 102,
                        "top": 794,
                        "height": 47,
                        "width": 269
                    },
                    "text": "INVOICE NUMBER",
                    "label": "invoice_label"
                }
            }
        }
  ]
```

But I want to restructure the json files into **this format**:

```
{
    "form": [
        {
            "box": [102,  794,  47,  269],
            "text": 'INVOICE NUMBER',
            "label": 'invoice_label'
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I automate this restructuring in python code.

Comment: I would suggest Python code that has a bunch of dict and list literals and some indexing operators.

Comment: Before you start writing the code you might want to consider the reason for having the value of *form* as a list. Why? There's no repetition in the source data

Comment: @Stuart The source data is itself a 1-item list.

Answer (score 0):

This really is just a trivial transformation, but here goes...

If you've loaded that data into a variable, say, `data`, then you'll get your desired output with

```
output = {
    "form": [
        {
            "box": [
                data[0]["INVOICE"]["label"]["box"]["left"],
                data[0]["INVOICE"]["label"]["box"]["top"],
                data[0]["INVOICE"]["label"]["box"]["height"],
                data[0]["INVOICE"]["label"]["box"]["width"],
            ],
            "text": data[0]["INVOICE"]["label"]["text"],
            "label": data[0]["INVOICE"]["label"]["label"],
        }
    ]
}
```

You might want to refactor this for less repetition by extracting `data[0]["INVOICE"]["label"]` into a variable:

```
label = data[0]["INVOICE"]["label"]
output = {
    "form": [
        {
            "box": [
                label["box"]["left"],
                label["box"]["top"],
                label["box"]["height"],
                label["box"]["width"],
            ],
            "text": label["text"],
            "label": label["label"],
        }
    ]
}
```

Finally, on the off-chance there are multiple items in the input `data`,

```
def transform_label(label):
    return {
        "box": [
            label["box"]["left"],
            label["box"]["top"],
            label["box"]["height"],
            label["box"]["width"],
        ],
        "text": label["text"],
        "label": label["label"],
    }


output = {
    "form": [
        transform_label(d["INVOICE"]["label"]) for d in data
    ]
}
```